# Refactor cyclomatic complexity

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have this piece of code with a high cyclomatic complexity:

```rb
def status_icon_name
  return 'icons/new.png' if mailgun_id.blank?
  return 'icons/hourglass.png' if mailgun_id.present? && log.blank?

  return 'icons/accept.png' if log['event'] == 'delivered'
  return 'icons/exclamation.png' if log['severity'].present? && log['severity'] == 'permanent'
  return 'icons/time.png' if log['event'] == 'accepted'
  return 'icons/error.png' if log['severity'] == 'temporary' 
  return 'icons/question.gif'
end
```

How can I refactor it to remove the cyclomatic complexity?

I have read this blog post [Cyclomatic complexity refactoring tips for javascript developers](https://sergeyski.com/cyclomatic-complexity-refactoring-tips/) and came up with  something like this but it doesn't feel right to me:

```rb
def status_icon_name
  lookup = [
    {
      condition: mailgun_id.blank?,
      icon_name: 'icons/new.png'
    },
    {
      condition: mailgun_id.present? && log.blank?,
      icon_name: 'icons/hourglass.png'
    },
    {
      condition: log.present? && log['event'] == 'delivered',
      icon_name: 'icons/accept.png'
    },
    {
      condition: log.present? && log['severity'].present? && log['severity'] == 'permanent',
      icon_name: 'icons/exclamation.png'
    },
    {
      condition: log.present? && log['event'] == 'accepted',
      icon_name: 'icons/time.png'
    },
    {
      condition: log.present? && log['severity'] == 'temporary',
      icon_name: 'icons/error.png'
    },
    {
      condition: true,
      icon_name: 'icons/question.gif'
    }
  ]

  lookup.find { |x| x[:condition] }[:icon_name]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Constructing a lookup table like this at runtime is counter-productive, you're generating this huge structure and evaluating *all* of those conditions regardless of their validity.

That is, when you write:

```
lookup = [
  {
    condition: mailgun_id.blank?,
    icon_name: 'icons/new.png'
  }
]
```

That gets immediately evaluated and reduced to something like:

```
lookup = [
  {
    condition: true,
    icon_name: 'icons/new.png'
  }
]
```

If you want deferred execution you need to use a `Proc`:

```
LOOKUP = [
  {
    condition: Proc.new { mailgun_id.blank? },
    icon_name: 'icons/new.png'
  }
]
```

Which you'd then execute like:

```
LOOKUP.find { |x| instance_eval(&x[:condition]) }[:icon_name]
```

That way you can store your lookup table as a constant at the top of your class and only need to define it once, not once per method call.